# Divisibility of a certain two variable polynomial by $x$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $F,G \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
(We do not know if $F$ and $G$ have a common zero or not).

Assume that there exists $H(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $H(0,0)=0$,
such that $x$ divides $H(Fy, Gy)$.

> When (= under which additional conditions) $x$ divides both $F$ and $G$?

**A special case:**  $H(x,y)=\lambda x+\mu y$. Then $H(Fy, Gy)= \lambda Fy +\mu Gy= y(\lambda F + \mu G)$. Then $x$ divides $\lambda F + \mu G$.
However, it may happen that $x$ does not divide either $F$ or $G$, for example, $\lambda=\mu=1$, $F=x+1$, $G=x-1$.

If $x$ divides $F$, then $x$ also divides $G$, and vice versa.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Also, is there a reason you switch back and forth between variables $x$ and $y$ and $X$ and $Y$, or are they the same?

Comment: @Servaes - how is $F(x,y)yG(F(x,y)y, G(x,y)y) - G(x,y)yF(F(x,y)y, G(x,y)y)$ always divisible by $x$? Besides which, it doesn't matter if such an $H$ always exists are not. The question is what additional conditions must $H$ satisfy to guarantee that $x$ also divides both $F$ and $G$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I guess the mixed use of upper- and lowercase variables tripped me up; I first thought of $H(X,Y)=XG-YF$, but then adjusted this to $H(X,Y)=XG(X,Y)-YF(X,Y)$ which certainly isn't always divisible by $x$. My comment doesn't make sense, I'll delete it and wait for clarification on the matter.

Comment: Are you considering conditions on $H$ alone, or also on $F$ and $G$?

Comment: @user237522 - I took the liberty of removing the variables $X, Y$ and functions $U, V$ from the post. I also found them more confusing than helpful. If you are not satisfied with the change, please feel free to change it back, and I apologize for it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thank you, your edit is good (you are right that there is no need for $U$ and $V$, and writing just $Fy$ and $Gy$ is better).

Comment: @Servaes, thanks for your comment; $\{x,y\}$ and $\{X,Y\}$ are indeed the same variables; I apologize for not being clear enough. "Are you considering conditions on $H$ alone, or also on $F$ and $G$?": Any conditions on $\{H,F,G\}$ are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the value of $y$ used in $F, G$, and just consider them functions of $x$ only, and include the $y$ multiples in the definitions of these functions instead of listing it separately. So $F = F(x), G = G(x)$ and we are given that $H(0,0) = 0$ and that $H(F(0), G(0)) = 0$, and want conditions so that this implies that $F(0) = 0$ and $G(0) = 0$.

This makes it obvious: the only such condition on $H$ alone is that $H$ can have only one root, namely the given one: $(0,0)$. If it has any other root, then we can choose $F, G$ so that $(F(0), G(0))$ is this root.

But this is impossible. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, for each $y$, either $H(x,y)$ is constant with respect to $x$, or else it has at least one root $x_y$, so $H(x_y, y) = 0$. But if $H$ is constant with respect to $x$ for all $y \ne 0$, then $H$ does not depend on $x$ at all, and therefore $H(F(0), G(0)) = 0$ would not imply that $F(0) = 0$.

So there is no condition on $H$ that will work. The only conditions on $F, G$ that could be added are that $(F(0), G(0))$ must miss the other roots of $H$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please, could you elaborate more on your last sentence about conditions on $F$ and $G$?

Comment: If you restrict $H$ so that there is some subset of $\Bbb C^2$ guaranteed to have no roots of $H$ other than $(0,0)$, and you restrict the choice of $F, G$ so that $(F(0), G(0))$ has to be in this set, then $H(F(0), G(0)) = 0$ will then imply $(F(0), G(0)) = (0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you! Please, I am not sure if I understand: Is it possible to find such a subset of $S \subsetneq \mathbb{C}^2$? (namely, $(0,0) \in S$ is the only root of $H$, and $(F(0),G(0)) \in S$).

Comment: Sure - you can even define $S = \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x,y) \mid H(x,y) \ne 0\}$. Then you place the restriction on $F,G$ that $(F(0), G(0)) \in S$. However, it seems to me that this is unlikely to be useful to you. I was just noting the concept against the rare case that something similar would be useful.

Comment: Thank you again.